# How can I watch iTunes tv shows/video on a DVD?

Tags: itunes, dvd, burning

Is it currently possible for me to buy a tv show season or movie on iTunes and then burn it to a DVD and watch it from a DVD player?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can archive copies of your TV shows or movies to a DVD using iTunes' included library backup feature, but they will not be viewable on DVD players.  You'll find that iTunes TV shows and movies include DRMs that will prevent you from playing them using most devices, though you do have a couple of options.

1. Plug your computer into your TV.  Requires S-Video, VGA, DVI or HDMI output from your computer and the same input from your TV.  (Avoid S-Video if possible--it only pumps 480p).
2. If you've got an iPod that plays video, you can buy [a ridiculously expensive cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB128LL/B?fnode=MTY1NDA0OQ&mco=MTA4MjUwNDc) from Apple to hook your iPod up to your TV.